# SSH tunnel over multi hops using putty (two hops)

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

I have these config:
Host with putty -- > Gateway A (port 22 open) --> FinalMachine (port 22 with gateway A open and port 18080 with apache).

Like I don't have communication from Host with putty with FinalMachine I would like to tunneling the connection to can connect directly from Host to 18080 of FinalMachine.

I'm trying to do with putty but I can't find the solution.
Anyone could help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1, using 2 instances of putty

- Putty 1: Local forward `20022:GatewayB:22`, Connect to `GatewayA`
- Putty 2: Local forward `18080:FinalMachine:18080`, Connect to `localhost:20022`

Method 2:

- Putty Local forward `18080:127.0.0.1:18080`,

  - From within session do next step `ssh -L 18080:FinalMachine:18080 GatewayB`

Comment: Sorry the Method 1 I can't understand. What is GatewayB??? Thanks

Comment: Problem is mine in the question redaction GatewayB is FinalMachine. I've edited the main question

Comment: Since you used "multi hops" and mentioned Gateway B I assumed there actually was a B machine. As long as `Gateway A` can access `FinalMachine:18080` you only need that one forward when connecting to `A`. On the other hand if `18080` is only accessible from `FinalMachine` itself, then use above, replace `B` with `Final` and possible change to localhost.